# Javascript - how to get just the value of the property after filtering and mapping the array of objects

Tags: javascript

I am filtering and mapping the array objects that looks like this:

```
taxonomy:Object
  data:Array[2]
    0:Object
      id:377
      name:"Buss"
      slug:"buss"
      type:"post_tag"
    1:Object
```

My function looks like this:

```
   let tag = this.article.taxonomy.data.filter(function( data ) {
      return data.type.includes('tag')
    }).map(function(obj) {
      return obj.name;
    });

    return tag;
```

What I am just wondering is there a way to get from the map function just the string name value,  since now it returns `["Buss"]`, so that don't need to use the index at the end of the function:

```
return tag[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), not `filter`, if you're looking only for **one** result. `find` returns the first entry for which the callback returns a truthy value, or `undefined` if it never does. So:

```
const obj = this.article.taxonomy.data.find(data => data.type.includes('tag'));
const tag = obj && obj.name; // Note the guard in case no entry matched
return tag;                  // Will be the name or `undefined`
```

*(Note that I've assumed you can use an arrow function, as you're using `let`. If not, just replace it with a `function` function.)*

Live Example:

```js
const taxonomy = {
    data: [
        {
            id: 375,
            name: "A",
            slug: "A",
            type: "nope"
        },
        {
            id: 376,
            name: "B",
            slug: "B",
            type: "nor-this"
        },
        {
            id: 377,
            name: "Buss",
            slug: "buss",
            type: "post_tag"
        },
        {
            id: 378,
            name: "C",
            slug: "C",
            type: "blah"
        }
    ]
};

const obj = taxonomy.data.find(data => data.type.includes('tag'));
const tag = obj && obj.name;
console.log(tag);
```